# Toolbox not showing custom workflow codeactivity in visual studio 2022

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, visual-studio-2022

I have created a sample workflow console app in visual studio 2019 and added a code activity named Login.cs. After compiling that, I am able to see that in Toolbox while loading xaml but when I open the same solution in Visual studio 2022, it doesn't show up with error "Activity could not be loaded because of errors in the XAML. Can you please advise.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNqX7.png)